# set umask for tomcat8 via tomcat.service

Tags: tomcat8, systemd, umask

I am trying to set a custom umask for a tomcat 8 instance, tried to make it the good way by using the UMask directive in systemd tomcat unit as seen [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#UMask=) without luck.

I'd like to set a 022 umask cause the company dev needs to access tomcat / application logs and they are not in the same group as the tomcat user....

the crazy thing is that the systemd doc says :

*Controls the file mode creation mask. Takes an access mode in octal notation. See umask(2) for details. Defaults to 0022.*

But the logs (application / tomcat) are set to 640 (not the expected 755) :

```
-rw-r----- 1 top top 21416 Feb  1 09:58 catalina.out
```

My service file :

```
# Systemd unit file for tomcat
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[...]

User=top
Group=top
UMask=0022

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any thoughts about this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try adding UMASK as Environment variable into tomcat's service file:

```
[Service]
...
Environment='UMASK=0022'
...
```

Default catalina.sh is checking for environment's $UMASK:

```
# Set UMASK unless it has been overridden
 if [ -z "$UMASK" ]; then
  UMASK="0027"
 fi
 umask $UMASK
```

(It seems to me, that [UMask from systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#UMask=) is not used by Tomcat, but I am not completely sure.)

Comment: Thanks for the input mjtecka I'll give it a try whenever I'll have time for this, I switched to another issue for now, I'll make sure to comeback here and accept your answer if that works !

Comment: This answer is correct and should be marked as such. UMask from systemd is being ignored by tomcat. This change works, as does simply changing the default umask found in catalina.sh

Comment: As suggested on catalina.sh: # Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a script setenv.sh in CATALINA_BASE/bin to keep your customizations separate.

Comment: @Tadgh got it working like a charm with systemd for tomcat9 on debian10. Just add a file called `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat9.service.d/override.conf` with the contents of the answer and make sure to refresh with `systemctl daemon-reload` otherwise it will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this with systemd by doing the following:

```
~]# mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service.d
~]# echo -e "[Service]\nUMask=0022" >/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service.d/custom-umask.conf
~]# systemctl daemon-reload
~]# systemctl restart tomcat
```

`/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service.d/umask-user.conf` should overwrite the default values.

Source: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2220161

P.S: A umask of `0022` would give a file `0644` permissions and a directory `0755`

Answer (score 1):

if using jsvc to start Tomcat as daemon process, then we need to set the -umask argument in jsvc command line

Answer (score 0):

You can add value to the UMASK variable in the file catalina.sh on Linux or catalina.bat on Windows, with 002 the file will be created with 775 permissions:

```
UMAKS=002
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat will use the `UMASK` environment variable definition.

```
UMASK=0022
```

Customised Tomcat environment variables should go in the `setenv.shl` file (Linux) or the `setenv.bat` file (Windows) in the `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/` directory/folder.