# File permissions log4j2 with RollingFile

Tags: file, permissions, log4j2, umask

I have problem with file permissions with RollingFile and log4j2 configuration.
Application is creating log file as follows:

`-rwxr-xr-x. 1 centos centos 10379932 Feb  8 13:55 application.log`

after rolling files read permissions for others are missing. I'm not using any permissions setting with log4j

```
-rw-r-----. 1 root   root        524 Feb  9 13:42 application.log
-rw-r-----. 1 root   root     462705 Feb  9 10:24 application.log.1.gz
```

umask is: `0022`

my log4j2.xml

```
        <RollingFile name="test_app" fileName="${sys:application.home}/logs/application.log" ignoreExceptions="false" filePattern="${sys:application.home}/logs/application.log.%i.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} - %X{userId} - %X{sessionId} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="50"/>
        </RollingFile>
```

I have 2 environments and on the second one permissions are as expected (application and log4j2 configuration is the same)
Where can I search the problem?

Comment: How is your application running? Are you sure the application does not overwrite the umask (e.g. Tomcat does overwrite it)? Is your application running as `root`? If not another process might be rotating the logs.

Comment: I have just find out that problem exists only on tomcat environment so I have to check tomcat umask. thanks for tip.

Comment: Tomcat overwrites `umask` in its initialization scripts: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41975808/11748454)